# Nondescript error when installing SQL 2014 Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2014

While installing SQL 2014 on a fresh Windows Server 2012 R2 machine I get the following error:

> Error result: -2068643838
>
> Result facility code: 1203
>
> Result error code: 2

It says to review `summary.txt`, but that file doesn't contain any further detail about the error. The only useful thing might be: `Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.NoopWorkflowException`

I also checked the error logs `Summary_myserver_20170629_154026.txt` in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log` but there doesn't seem to be anything descriptive there.

Maybe I'm missing something in how these log files are intended to be read, but I'm at a loss here. I checked the firewall settings, restarted, verified credentials...

**Edit:** .NET 3.5 and .NET 4+ are both installed and enabled.

**Edit:** There are no other SQL programs installed. Programs and Features is empty except for MS Visual C++ Redistributable.

**Edit:** Not sure if it's relevant, but this is when my .ini file has QuietSimple set to true. When I set it to false, I get to the "Feature Review" screen, which won't let me check any boxes. It says "All features are already configured. Click cancel to exit", and won't let me click next. Very strange, as like I said, there is no SQL or SQL features on this computer.

Comment: Have you double and triple checked all the Server 2012 R2 machine prerequisites for the Server 2014 software? Perhaps you need to add the [.NET Framework 3.5 Features](https://i.imgur.com/c5E7lYL.png) and then try to reinstall. Check out the [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2014](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx) for SQL Server 2014 when you get a chance. Tag me back if you find any of this helpful in resolving your problem and if you'd like me to add anything as an answer. Good enough for a starting point for you perhaps though.

Comment: @McDonald's I just finished double checking. .NET 3.5 is all installed and enabled. The hardware and software requirements all check out.

Comment: Additionally, be sure you run the setup as an administrator or right click and run as administrator and UAC is not an issue. If the installation process security context is not elevated beforehand, then the installation process may not be able to access a resource, etc. that having this access to the OS would allow otherwise. Just thinking about eliminating the simple stuff or at least confirming that's not the issue.

Comment: @McDonald's Yeah, good call. The installer is kicked off via PowerShell mounting the .iso (so it can use a .ini file and `Add-DomainUserToLocalGroup`, etc), which has the execution policy properly set and is run as administrator. All Windows updates are up to date. I've used the PowerShell script on a ton of other servers, so I know it works.

Comment: Check your environment variable TEMP for both user and system.

Comment: @harrymc What am I checking them for?

Comment: That they point to existing folders.

Comment: Could you check the other log files? See [this list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/955396/how-to-identify-sql-server-2008-setup-issues-in-the-setup-log-files)

Comment: @harrymc C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp does exist and has a sqlsetup log file in it.

Comment: @TomV That list is for SQL 2008, so many of those log files don't exist on my system. I did check the log files that do exist, and couldn't find anything that went wrong before the error.

Comment: @McDonald's Just double checked, no SQL stuff is currently installed.

Comment: Are you prompted to install a service pack during the installation? If so, don't install it. Also, try setting the Account Name for the **SQL Server Database Engine** service to SYSTEM account. You can change it back to what you need it to be after the install, and install the SP afterward too if it's successful.

Comment: @McDonald's added some more detail... I did verify the PS version and those two Windows updates. All looks well.

Comment: @Twisty No service pack prompt. I don't think I'm getting far enough to set the SQL Server Database Engine to anything. Unless that's a config file setting I can tweak?

Comment: @coinbird Before the install begins you get to choose what account the database instance will run in. What components are you selecting for install at the beginning of setup?

Comment: What a sec...you're using an .ini file to configure the setup? Please share more about that. Everyone here has probably been assuming you're doing a standard install!

Comment: @Twisty It's really just setting accounts. SQLSVCACCOUNT, SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS, etc. It sets a few log file locations as well, the locations do exist. ACTION="CompleteImage", a few other things. Any specifics that you think are relevant?

Comment: @coinbird Given we don't know what's causing the error, no, at this point I can't say what of these may be involved. I suggest you take the .ini file out of the equation until you can get past the error.

Comment: @McDonald's Edit: I ran a little PowerShell to confirm: $t ='*sql*';Get-Service | Where {($_.Name -like "$t" -or $_.DisplayName -like "$t") -and $_.StartType -ne "Disabled"}

Turns up no results.

Comment: That may only confirm if you have some sort of SQL service running though I think without looking at your PowerShell without a lot of detail. If there is some redistributable component that's installed and hosed up, then this would likely not show you that. Give this a simple shot, move forward with the SQL Server install from the GUI, uninstall it, then reboot and rerun your process again. You have yet to provide any content for the PowerShell install you are running nor any of the ini detail as others suggested. This is not rocket science and you should be able to resolve easily -- just try.

Comment: @McDonald's it turned out to be the "ACTION" parameter. Dumb mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this one. The issue was running the install with the config parameter ACTION="CompleteImage".

The correct parameter is ACTION="PrepareImage".

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered error -2068643838 when the SQL product being installed has already been installed. This is for both SQL Server 2019, and a patch for 2019.

Here's an [example online of this outcome](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1f4b898d-e012-49cd-aa7b-fb30065ca88c/the-security-patch-kb3045313-failed-on-sql-server-2008-r2?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade) for a security patch for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thus, this isn't really an error, more so a status exit code.